# Heroku Personal Hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to understand how heroku works. Ok I get 1 dyno free, and if I register a domain I can have my own website, example "www.mysite.com" on heroku. I prefer heroku because uploading rails app is really easy. But how fast is 1 dyno? Why 1 dyno is free and 2 are 35 dollar? So I have to pay minimum 35 dollars per month when I can get hosting like http://www.site5.com which is 5 dollars per month? Can somebody clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3):

They do not make it obvious in the documentation, but a single dyno will go into a suspended state after 30 minutes of inactivity. This saves them a bit of money, but comes with the trade-off that the first request it receives will have a bit higher latency because the dyno has to wake up.

In my experience, a single Heroku dyno performs better than an Amazon EC2 micro instance, which has ~600MB of RAM.

Once you upgrade to two dynos, they will no longer go into this suspended state.